# Transmissão tipo 'livestreaming' com javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de *Livestreaming*(Transmissão ao vivo de vídeo) e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer essa transmissão usando `websockets`, `javascript` e `html5 video capture` onde teria uma página web que iria capturar o vídeo da webcam(com *html5 video capture*) e outra onde teria um *player* que iria passar o vídeo capturado em tempo real.

Alguém teria alguma referencia sobre ou sabe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Acredito, que lendo a documentação do firefox hello você vai ver que quase tudo é possivel. https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/hello/

Comment: Olhe esse link cara: >Simple webcam with websockets and Processing Bad Ankles http://badankles.com/?p=209 *Bad Ankles*

Comment: Precisei um tempo atrás para um projeto que não acabou saindo do papel, e na época consegui ter um rumo para seguir após esta referência, talvez ajude: [http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets)

Comment: Um link Tutorial em inglês pra você compreender melhor: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7NsiFXcc5A

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a tecnologia `webRTC` que está presente na versão Chrome 18+. Mas você precisa entrar em about:// flags e ativar o 'getUserMedia()' ou MediaStream. Use o control F para encontrar com facilidade.

Aqui vai um código que encontrei no github que testei e funcionou:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.oslikas.com/js/WebRTCO-1.0.4-beta-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span4" id="div_video_local">
            <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" id="localVideo" muted="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="div_video_remote">
            <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" id="remoteVideo1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="span2"></div>
    </div>
```

Coloquei esta resposta porque acredito que ninguém irá trazer algo realmente funcional(gratuito) por um bom tempo. Existem muitos projetos no github, mas muitos parados ou com bugs. Alguns eram grátis e tornaram-se pagos. Mas é um teste legal pra fazer, mas para negócio ainda não é uma boa.

Link dos arquivos: https://github.com/fycth/webrtcexample

Link de teste: https://www.webrtcexample.com/ ou https://www.webrtcexample.com/chat.html

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não está errado! :)

Comment: Sim. Realmente não tem aquele espaço. Mas é o site que está colocando automático. Quando edito está normal. Estranho :/

Comment: Não foi o site não, eu consegui editar normal, veja só, você deve ter copiado com quebra de linha e quando virou "html" aparece como espaço.